# Handle ADOException on SaveOrUpdate, retrieve data that fail to insert

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Here's how we are currently doing the save or update of a list of objects:

```
        ISession sess = GetSession(true);
        try
        {
            foreach (MonType oe in pListobject)
            {
                sess.SaveOrUpdate(oe);
            }
            CommitTransaction();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            try
            {
                RollBackTransaction();
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            throw ex;
        }
```

It works well, but now I want to handle the exceptions on a list of objects to determine which attribute on which object fail to insert/update.

For example, considering a list of object Foo:

```
List 
new Foo(){pkAtt1 ='123', Att2='456'}
new Foo(){pkAtt1 ='789', Att2='12/12/2015'}
```

I want to know that the object Foo with the pkAtt1='789' failed to insert because the Att2 equals to '12/12/2015'
Currently, the ADOException provide me not enough information to do that:

> INSERT INTO FOO (ATTR1, ATTR2) VALUES (?, ?)}

With only this kind of information:

> Excess SqlDateTime. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 31/12/9999 11:59:59 PM.

Someone knows how to achieve that ? 
Thanks for the help ! :)

Comment: dont say `throw ex`; just `throw` or you will swallow the stack trace when you catch it outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to log the details of the object which caused exception. log it there it self.

```
ISession sess = GetSession(true);
foreach (MonType oe in pListobject)
{
  try
  {
    sess.SaveOrUpdate(oe);
  }
  catch
  {
    Log("Object details", oe.details);//Add whatever details you want to log
    RollBackTransaction();
    throw; // dont throw ex
  }
}
CommitTransaction();
```

**Edit**
You don't need the outer try catch in my previous, just updated my answer with better approach.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for :D I didn't know that the SaveOrUpdate "logged" the error, I though it was when the CommitTransaction happens. thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

If you use Entity Framework you can catch the `DbException` and get the Entity for which the exception is thrown. Something like

```
    ISession sess = GetSession(true);
    try
    {
        foreach (MonType oe in pListobject)
        {
            sess.SaveOrUpdate(oe);
        }
        CommitTransaction();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException ex)
    {
        var entry = ex.Entries.Single(); //get the entity
        // do your stuff
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        try
        {
            RollBackTransaction();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        throw ex;
    }
```